# I am working on Fullcalendar.io library, I am not able to display additional information in listMonth

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image: listMonth in fullcalendar i need to display additional information here]

I want to display additional information in `listMonth` in `fullCalendar` other than start, end, times, color and title (see picture). I want to display faculty and description as well, in the list. I have added faculty and description in the UI as well as in the database. I want them to be displayed in list (see picture).

```php
    <?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
$date = date("Y-m-d");
?>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                header: {

                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    //right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth,'
                },

                navLinks: true,
                defaultDate: '<?php echo$date?>',
                minTime: '00:00:00',
                maxTime: '24:00:00',
                editable: true,
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                slotMinutes: 15,

                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                selectable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function (start, end) {

                    $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
                },
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.bind('dblclick', function () {
                        $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                        $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                        $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                        $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                    });
                },
                eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                    edit(event);

                },
                eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                    edit(event);

                },
                events: [
        <?php foreach($events as $event):
                    $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else {
                $start = $event['start'];
            }
            if ($end[1] == '00:00:00') {
                $end = $end[0];
            } else {
                $end = $event['end'];
            }
        ?>
                {
                //  id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                    faculty: '<?php echo $event['faculty']; ?>',
                    description: '<?php echo $event['description']; ?>',
                },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        ]
        });

        function edit(event) {
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss');
            if (event.end) {
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss');
                //HH:mm:ss
            } else {
                end = start;
            }

            id = event.id;

            Event = [];
            Event[0] = id;
            //Event[1] = start;
            //Event[2] = end;


            $.ajax({
                url: 'editEventDate.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: { Event: Event },
                success: function (rep) {
                    if (rep == 'OK') {
                        alert('SAVED');
                    } else {
                        alert('Could not be saved. try again.');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

});

    </script>
```

Comment: What picture? I don't see a link

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjs7r7xn4PgAhUOh7wKHSyGC64QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F40135126%2Ffullcalendar-list-view-multi-day-events-not-grouping-correctly&psig=AOvVaw2u3nf-nNxcxp1cDsRi1FzE&ust=1548310398450906

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting a comment.

Comment: check now i have uploaded the image

Comment: Please help me with this man ...

Comment: I need it urgently

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this would help you, as you are using only title combine three information into one title like below, i.e as you using PHP as server language combine (title,faculty, description) in to a array and implode("-",$array)

```js
var events = []

$(function() {
  
  var $calendar = $('#calendar')
  $calendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },
    defaultDate: '2010-01-01',
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    editable: true,

    events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
      callback(events)
    }
    
  })

  // 30 ms delay
  setTimeout( function() {    
    events.push.apply(events, [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2010-01-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 1 - FactulyName - Description',
        start: '2009-02-07',
        end: '2010-01-10'
      }
    ] )
    $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
  }, 30)


})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.2/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.2/fullcalendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```